# SDK 2: % done column

Tags: rally

I'd like to use a % done field that uses the same functionality as % done by story plan estimate for portfolio items, except for another field.

What I'd like to do is create the same sort of bar for defects which have been marked as must fix for a particular release, and then show % done by plan estimate.  I can handle getting the list of defects, calculating % done etc.

Can you show me an example of how to display such a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a [PercentDoneTemplate](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.renderer.template.PercentDoneTemplate) in the SDK 2.0p3 release, but it is currently private in the SDK. You can use it, but at the risk of us changing it on you in the future. We are considering making it a publicly supported component. To use it in a grid, you just need to add a `templatecolumn` column to your `columnCfg`, something like this:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    store: myStore,
    columnCfgs: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        flex: 1
    },
    {
        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.PercentDoneTemplate')
    }]  
});
```

The template is expecting your data to have a field called `percentDone` (case sensitive). You can change that by adding a config option for `percentDoneName`

```
{
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.PercentDoneTemplate', {
         percentDoneName: 'myPercentDoneField'
    }),
}
```

It should end up looking like:

[image: grid with percent done template]

Comment: I tried this, but first needed to enable the loader: Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});  But even then, I get a pretty obscure error: TypeError: c is not a constructor
  ....instantiators[length] = new Function('c', 'a', 'return new c('+args.join(',')+'...  What did I miss here do you think?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? You can find that in the url to sdk.js. Is it 2.0p, 2.0p2 or 2.0p3?

Comment: I was using 2.0p2-- didn't realize 2.0p3 was available-- I switched to that and its working.  BTW, can you control the color?

Answer (score 2):

If you can calculate the percentage as a decimal, then you can easily generate a rallypercentdone component. However, I don't know how you expect to place them in a column. Perhaps a Rally dev will be able to better assist you in that regard.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.PercentDone